# VMWare Player 15.5.1 - cannot start GUI - vmmon cannot be installed

Tags: kali-linux

[image][image]
I cannot start VMWare Player 15.5.1. - vmmon gives an error - see picture

vmmon not close to kernal

Comment: Log File is to large for comment

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the release ->

```
sudo wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/player-16.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf player-16.2.0.tar.gz
cd vmware-host-modules-player-16.2.0
tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This VMWare release is too old for your running kernel.

Please either install the latest VMWare release, 16.2.0, or [patch](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules) its kernel modules.

Comment: The release 16.2.0 helps. Thanks a lot Artem!

Comment: Yes that is correct - with "kernal 5.10.0" it works